# How to read a string from user with spaces

Tags: java, string

My program will be given this as an input:

```
1 T T T T T F T T F F
Bobb, Bill 123456789  T T T T T F T T F F
Lou, Mary  974387643  F T T T T F T T F F
Bobb, Sam  213458679  F T F T f t 6 T F f
Bobb, Joe  315274986  t t t t t f t t f f
ZZZZ
```

Code:

```
BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer (br.readLine ());
String key = st.nextToken ();
```

How do I read the first line in as a single string?

I've tried using a string tokenizer but that only grabs the `1` and drops the rest. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show your code.

Comment: If you just need the line as a whole why are you even using the tokenizer?

Comment: Scanner class to read the line as one string then split on space. boom.

Comment: Like @3kings said, a scanner class should be sufficient...  Or read until meet a "/n" character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
    // you can stop taking input when input line is empty
    if(line.isEmpty()){  
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(line); // printing the input line  
}
br.close();
```

**See [live demo](https://ideone.com/xjrtsJ)**

Comment: so this program will continue to reading input from the user until there is no input from the keyboard?

Comment: @FlyingBurrito yes, you are correct. Is your problem solved? If my answer helped you, you can accept it.

Comment: thank you now if i wanted this program to terminate when given the input "ZZZZ" or "zzzz" would i change the line"if(line.isEmpty())" to "if(line == "ZZZZ" && "zzzz")"

Comment: for string comparison, use `equals()` method. you don't need to check for both upper and lower case letters. say you can do something like this - `if(line.toLowerCase().equals("zzzz"))`. By the way, if you have different problems, you can ask multiple questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

all arguments are stored in the args array.

```
StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) { 
         input.append(args[i]+" "); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to decrease the line count. Also, you can't forget to close the stream when doing so.

**Based on Wasi Ahmad's answer**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{      
        String line;        
        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){                  
                if(line.isEmpty()){  // Stop reading
                    break;
                }                   
                // Print line
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did :-) I'm not quite sure I can follow. What do you mean with _overwrite the previous line_?